# no error for missing c++ function declaration

Tags: g++, hoisting

With g++, compiling the following code will return `error: ‘test’ was not declared in this scope`.  But Arduino C++ compiler will **NOT** fail as such.  Why?  And how can I get gcc/g++ to hoist functions like the Arduino compiler apparently does?

```
void setup() {
  test();
}

void loop() {}

int test() { return 1; }
```

I've felt for a long time that if Javascript, Perl, etc. can hoist functions, it seems beyond reasonable for the C/C++ pre-processor to allow the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably need an additional preprocessor for that. I have personally never tried it, but maybe [protoize](https://linux.die.net/man/1/protoize) would be interesting for you!